# Compiler error on code after a return

Tags: java, compilation, return

I'm getting a compiler error on the following code (snippet).  Why is this code incorrect? an solution

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int paramInt)
{
 switch (paramInt)
 {
 default:
 case 0:
 }
 for (Object localObject = null; ; localObject = this.dialog)
 {
  return localObject; // here problem cast
  this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  this.dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(2131165201));
  this.dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
  this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: _Did you read the message?_

Comment: In the future, you will always want to post the error message with your question. It usually holds the key to the problem, as it does in this case, since it tells you (and us) exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Interesting for loop too. Why the very strange loop?

Comment: `return localObject; // here problem cast`  Please *copy/paste* the error rather than paraphrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having `return` statement before `this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);` which becomes `unreachable` code because control will never reach to the next direct statement after return statement. **This will result into compilation error.** You need to flip the order as:

```
    for (Dialog localObject = null; ; localObject = this.dialog)
    {
       this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
       return localObject;
     }
```

I am not sure what your loop will do but one thing is sure that it will not loop but simply return in first iteration itself. Also your `localObject` will remain `null` as it will not reach the `increment` block of the `for` loop(it returns beforehand because of return statement).

**EDIT:** Just to fix your compilation error, move your return statement in the bottom of the `loop` as:

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int paramInt)
    {
       switch (paramInt)
       {
         default:
         case 0:
       }
       for (Dialog localObject = null; ; localObject = this.dialog)
       {
          this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
          this.dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(2131165201));
          this.dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
          this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
          return localObject; // here problem cast
       }
      }
```

As I mentioned earlier, I am not getting the real reason of using the `for` loop as it's not going to loop at all because of the `return` statement inside.

Comment: +1, but the key point you're missing is that directly unreachable code will not compile.

Comment: @Vulcan: I explicitly added the message stating the same.

Comment: error at compilation, "cannot convert from Object to Dialog"

Comment: @user1854920 You `localObject` declaration should be of type `Dialog` instead of `Object` i.e. `Dialog localObject = null`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (or shouldn't) have any code after a return.  It's called "dead"or "unreachable" code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Object localObject = null; ; localObject = this.dialog) {
   return localObject;
   this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
}
```

First of all, you are returning localObject, which is set to null. Not sure if that is giving you a Null Pointer Exception or not, but it seems fishy. Secondly, as Yogendra said, the program never reaches the `this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);` statement as anything after a return statement becomes dead code.